# Palatino, roman \chi and the math mode

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, koma-script

I am using Palatino for the content and I have a problem displaying \chi in math mode. The problem happens when I have a roman formatting in math, e.g., vector **x**, **X**, and **χ**; the χ turns to some other character.

### The minimal example

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,english,titlepage, a4paper, fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}


%show vectors in bold
\renewcommand\vec[1]{\mathrm{\mathbf{#1}}}
%end renew commands

\title{Brief Article}
\author{The Author}
\begin{document}

\noindent Three different systems of reference are used within this
work. Structural deformations are described in the Lagrangian or material
formulation. The corresponding Lagrangian coordinate system denoted
by $\vec{X}$ is associated with the particular material points. The Eulerian or
spatial system of reference denoted by $\vec{x}$,
in which the observer is fixed in space and looks at the fluid passing.
In the ALE description of the motion, a third reference system, denoted
by $\vec{\chi}$.
\end{document}
```

which produces the following image:

[image: chi is not shown correct]

What I would like to have is this [1]:

[image: chi is shown correct]

How can I fix this?

[1] The difference is that I removed `\usepackage{mathpazo}` from the top.

Comment: A minimal example would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as your vectors are only Roman or Greek letters, the following works

```
\usepackage{bm}

%show vectors in bold
\DeclareRobustCommand\vec[1]{%
  \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax
    \expandafter\bm
  \else
    \expandafter\mathbf
  \fi{#1}}
%end renew commands
```

Your `\mathrm` serves no purpose. The problem is that there's no Greek letter in the font used by `\mathbf`, so we resort to the `\bm` macros of package **bm**.

**Caution** This works only with one letter as the argument.

An alternative can be simply

```
\usepackage{bm}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm}
```

but Roman letters will be in boldface (math) italic.

Comment: The `\mathrm` makes `\vec{X}` an upright letter, doesn't it? It serves no purpose _for greek letters_

Comment: @Seamus `\mathXY` commands work differently from `\textXY` commands: their effect are not cumulative, since they simply choose a different alphabet. The usual alphabet associated to `\mathbf` is "upright boldface".

Comment: Ah right. I see that now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Isn't `\let\vec\bm` simpler than `\renewcommand`ing it? Or is `\let`ing things a bad idea?

Comment: It's not a bad idea; with `\renewcommand` we would always use the current meaning of `\bm`; with `\let` the meaning is frozen.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\newcommand\vec[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}` makes your chi appear bold. Unfortunately, I can't get it to play nice with `\mathrm`

Answer (score 0):

try this setting instead:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[uprightgreeks]{kpfonts}
```

the kpfonts are similiar to the palatino fonts.